# Ninject with WCF service - Dispose() not fired

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have a WCF service which has some lower level services as constructor parameters, thay are injected via Ninject and have a db context in them. All constructor parameters are IDisposable. The service looks like this:

```
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class DirectoryService : IDirectoryService
    {
        private IDomainService DomainService { get; set; }

        public DirectoryService(IDomainService domainService)
        {
            DomainService = domainService;
        }
        ...
    }
```

I would like to dispose these instances after each method call complete, I've tried to set up my bindings as follows:

```
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IDomainService>().To<DomainService>().InScope(x => OperationContext.Current);
            ...
        }
```

also like this:

```
            private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
            {
                kernel.Bind<IDomainService>().To<DomainService>().InScope(x => HttpContext.Current);
                ...
            }
```

and like this:

```
                private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
                {
                    kernel.Bind<IDomainService>().To<DomainService>().InRequestScope();
                    ...
                }
```

still none of the options really disposes my items after a successfull call to the service, any ideas are welcome, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR `.InScope()` (`HttpContext.Current` or `OperationContext.Current`) both work - but not how you would expect it. Ninject will keep a `WeakReference` to the scope object and periodically check whether it was collected. If it was collected, it will dispose the object in it's scope. If there's no memory pressure this can take a long time.

`InRequestScope();` should work if you've got [Ninject.Extensions.Wcf](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/) installed. But beware, you also need to make sure you've got the latest version of [Ninject.Web.Common - 3.2.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.Common/3.2.3) because there was an [issue with a previous version where `.InRequestScope()` didn't work](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/issues/15).

Comment: Ninject.Extensions.Wcf is installed, had Ninject.Web.Common - 3.2.0, updated to the latest version but still no luck, any other ideas?

Comment: Oh yes you need to bind the class, not the interface `.InRequestScope()`. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529592/wcf-using-ninject-dispose-not-triggering-in-requestscope?rq=1. Please give feedback whether this was your issue. If so, we can mark it as a duplicate. This helps increasing the quality of the site (different people search for the same answer by posing different questions, what is totally ok b/c this way others have a better chance of finding it per google. It's just that there should be a single solution/answer thread)

Comment: Just tried to change my binding to kernel.Bind<IDomainService, DomainService>().To<DomainService>().InRequestScope(); - nothing changed, Dispose() is not called

Comment: Can you add an `.OnActivation()` and therein set a breakpoint/write to console or something - so you can verify that really this binding is used?

Comment: Changed to  kernel.Bind<IDomainService, DomainService>().To<DomainService>().InRequestScope().OnActivation(x => Debug.WriteLine("Domain Service"));  The output window showed: Domain Service

Comment: ok in this case i think you should create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and file it as a bug [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/issues).